# Perpendicular distance from chord to circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I need to find the perpendicular distance from a chord to the circle, at arbitrary distance along the chord. I found an approximation using versine, but is there an exact formula?

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The perpendicular distance, if I understand this correctly, is just the distance from the point to the circle, **along** the radius. So given a cord, and a point on it, you can calculate the $x$ and $y$ positions of the point in terms of the distance from one end. Then the distance between that point and the circle is just $R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. You would need to give more information about how you define the cord, in order to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let a unit circle

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

and a horizontal chord

$$y=h.$$

The vertical distance is given by

$$y-h=\sqrt{1-x^2}-h,$$ for $x$ in $\left[-\sqrt{1-h^2},\sqrt{1-h^2}\right].$

Comment: Thanks !  That's it.In my case, I know the length of cord, from which I can determine h from actual radius.